# How can I load an assembly from a byte[] for use in a Razor view in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

**Background**
Hello! Our .NET 5 web application follows a "plug-in" architecture. We have different modules throughout the website that are unique enough to warrant their own projects inside of our solution. At the start of the application, our 'main' application loads the compiled DLLs. Currently, we are in the process of migrating our application to the cloud and moving toward a micro service architecture. Ultimately, we are attempting to store compiled DLLs in AWS S3, download them on application start, and load them.

**Methods**
We are able to get the DLL from S3 without a problem. As far as we can tell, there are 3 possible ways to load the DLL. The object stream from S3 is named "dll".

(Preferred):

```
var assm = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(dll);
mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(assm);
```

(Less favorable, but not bad):

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     dll.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     var b =  memoryStream.ToArray();
     var assm = Assembly.Load(b);
     mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(assm);
}
```

(Least favorable):

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/tmp/Anon.dll", FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
{
     dll.CopyTo(fileStream);
     var assm = Assembly.LoadFile(name);
     mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(assm);
}
```

**Errors / Unexpected Behavior**
The problem is that methods 1 and 2, which are most favorable, do not work. The application returns a detailed error message (stack trace is found below). If we use the very same DLL from S3 and simply load it to a temporary location, the DLL loads as expected. It is also worth mentioning that if the DLL is already stored locally as a file, converted to a stream, and attempted to load - we receive the same error. Are we doing something wrong? Is there a limitation that we are not aware of?

```
ArgumentException: Empty path name is not legal. (Parameter 'path')
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int bufferSize, FileOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.CreateMetadataReference(string path)
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>.ToList()
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(string normalizedPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet<IChangeToken> expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13312).

Comment: @JeroenMostert This helped solve our issue. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Running assemblies directly from the web is not a good idea. For starters, if S3 is down, all your applications are down. If S3 is slow, all your applications start up slowly. If your S3 account gets compromised, all your applications are compromised. If you replace an assembly with a breaking version, all applications are dead. The list of problems is endless, with what benefits?

That being said, your problem is that Razor runs its own compilation, and it apparently, given the stack trace, wants to load assembly metadata from disk. Your assembly-from-stream has a path in it somewhere that's null.

The immediate solution: cache them on disk, which is a good step in the direction you should take anyway, or are you really really sure you want to download all DLLs again for each application pool recycle?

Comment: Our application has about 10 modules at this point - we will be hosting them either on Elastic Beanstalk or containers. Our goal is to be able to update one of these plugin modules without affecting the rest of the site, so hosting it outside of the application server and triggering an update appears to be the best way so far. Do you have any other recommendations on how we could do that?